# Exception: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query SELECT MAX(cast(value,integer))

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, named-query

I have a query:

```
<query name="getMaxId">
       <![CDATA[from  Identifier where value = (select MAX (cast(value, integer)) from Identifier where type = :type) ]]>
    </query>
```

where value is: `<property name="value" type="java.lang.String" column="value" not-null="true"/>`

and try to invoke it with:

```
Query q = getSession().getNamedQuery("getMaxId");
q.setString("type", type);
List<Identifier> results = q.list();
```

However I get an error:

> Exception: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not
> execute query
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number

I also tried

```
<![CDATA[from  Identifier where value = (select MAX (to_number(value)) from Identifier where type = :type) ]]>
```

but then I receive

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node:
> org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.AggregateNode

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: And the problem SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Not the proper solution to this problem but kind of workaround is pure SQL instead of HQL:

```
createSQLQuery("SELECT MAX (to_number(value)) FROM ids");
```